# Subquery in SELECT using Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to convert this kind of SQL into ActiveRecord query in Yii2:

```
SELECT 
*,
(select count(*) from pendaftar where pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_1 =  a.id_prodi_penerima)as jum1,
(select count(*) from pendaftar where pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_2 = a.id_prodi_penerima)as jum2 
FROM prodi_penerima as a
```

I have two relational models that are `Pendaftar` and `ProdiPenerima`.

This is `Pendaftar` model:

```
...
* @property ProdiPenerima $prodiPilihan1
* @property ProdiPenerima $prodiPilihan2
...
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPekerjaanIdPekerjaan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Pekerjaan::className(), ['id_pekerjaan' => 'pekerjaan_id_pekerjaan']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getUserPendaftar()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_user_pendaftar']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getProdiPilihan1()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProdiPenerima::className(), ['id_prodi_penerima' => 'prodi_pilihan_1']);
}
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getProdiPilihan2()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProdiPenerima::className(), ['id_prodi_penerima' => 'prodi_pilihan_2']);
}
```

And this is `ProdiPenerima` model:

```
...
* @property Pendaftar[] $pendaftars
* @property Pendaftar[] $pendaftars0
...
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPendaftars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Pendaftar::className(), ['prodi_pilihan_1' => 'id_prodi_penerima']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getPendaftars0()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Pendaftar::className(), ['prodi_pilihan_2' => 'id_prodi_penerima']);
}
```

`prodi_pilihan_1` and `prody_pilihan_2` are foreign keys in `pendaftar` table, that key was referenced from `ProdiPenerima` table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$result = ProdiPenerima::find()
    ->select([
        '*',
        'jum1' => Pendaftar::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->where('pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_1 = a.id_prodi_penerima'),
        'jum2' => Pendaftar::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->where('pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_2 = a.id_prodi_penerima')
    ])
    ->alias('a')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Results can be accessed by:

```
foreach ($result as $row) { 
    echo $row['jum1']; 
}
```

That because [`asArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail) was used, so query return array of arrays instead of array of models.

---

If you need models, you should add properties into your models to store result of subqueries:

```
class ProdiPenerima extends ActiveRecord {

    public $jum1;
    public $jum2;

    // ...
}
```

Then remove `isArray()` from query:

```
$result = ProdiPenerima::find()
    ->select([
        '*',
        'jum1' => Pendaftar::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->where('pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_1 = a.id_prodi_penerima'),
        'jum2' => Pendaftar::find()
            ->select(['COUNT(*)'])
            ->where('pendaftar.prodi_pilihan_2 = a.id_prodi_penerima')
    ])
    ->alias('a')
    // ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Results can be accessed by:

```
foreach ($result as $model) { 
    echo $model->jum1; 
}
```

But note that using `asArray()` will be faster, so unless you need access some model methods (or rely on typecasting of values from DB) I would prefer arrays.

Comment: Nice, i didnt knew that we can do it this way, nice answer like always.

Comment: I have render that model into view, then  try to access that model in the view like this `<?php foreach($result as $result) { 
                  echo $result->jum; 
                
              }`,  but i got error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: i have edit my comment, i have typo jum instead jum1, but still same error, I have render that model into view, then try to access that model in the view like this `<?php foreach($result as $result) { echo $result->jum1; }`, but i got error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i have try `var_dump($result);` and give me the array with the value, but why when i try access them with `<?php foreach($result as $result) { echo $result->jum1; }` i got error Trying to get property of non-object