# Yii2: Access column by alias

Tags: database, yii2

When querying with alias names, how to access a colum by its alias **without** declaring in the model?

```
$values = Value::find()
    ->addSelect("min(y) as MINVAL")
    ->groupBy(...)
    ->all();
foreach($values as $v) {
    echo $v->x;     // accessing a property of ActiveRecord class Value
    echo $v->???    // how to access MINVAL?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subquery in SELECT using Yii2 ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581521/subquery-in-select-using-yii2-activerecord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general depend of the type of collection you obtain  (array, or object)

if the result is  an array then

```
echo  $v['MINVAL'];
```

In your case should be an object then

```
  echo  $v->MINVAL;
```

find()....->all() should return activeRecord (object) so you should access via $v->MINVAL;;

for this you should add  the MINVAL declaration in Value class

```
 class Value
 {
   public MINVAL;  
   .....
```

Or try obtaining the result as an array

```
 find()->asArray()->all();
 Value::find()
->addSelect("min(y) as MINVAL")
->groupBy(...)->asArray()->all();
```

and access using

```
echo  $v['MINVAL'];
```

Comment: When accessing by array index I get this error: ```Getting unknown property: app\models\Value::MINVAL```

Comment: I cannot expand the model. Please see my question.

Comment: answer updated ..  (you could alse extendd the Value class  as you prefer)

Comment: Thank you, it as ```->asArray()``` what I was missing