# Yii2, SELECT from two joined tables as ActiveRecord

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, yii2

Have 2 tables:

1. **product_url** (`id`,`product_id`,`url`)

   | id | product_id | url |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1234 | http://example.org/sku1234.html |
   | 2 | 1234 | http://anotherdomain.com/alice-book.html |
   | 3 | 1234 | http://bookstore.com/Alices-Adventures-in-Wonderland.html |
   | 4 | 4321 | http://example.org/sku4321.html |
2. **shop** (`id`,`url`,`tag`)

   | id | url | tag |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | http://example.org/ | low |
   | 2 | http://anotherdomain.com/ | med |
   | 3 | http://bookstore.com/ | hig |

(!) I do ActiveQuery select from two joined tables (product_url + shop ) on SUBSTRING_INDEX **as Array**.

```
$product_url = ProductUrl::find()
    ->alias('pu')
    ->select('pu.*, tag')
    ->leftJoin('shop', "SUBSTRING_INDEX(pu.url, '/', 3) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(shop.url, '/', 3)")
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

and expected to get a data like this

**product_url_tag** (`id`,`product_id`,`url`,`tag`)

```
| id | product_id | url                                                       | tag |
|----|------------|-----------------------------------------------------------|-----|
| 1  | 1234       | http://example.org/sku1234.html                           | low |
| 2  | 1234       | http://anotherdomain.com/alice-book.html                  | med |
| 3  | 1234       | http://bookstore.com/Alices-Adventures-in-Wonderland.html | hig |
| 4  | 4321       | http://example.org/sku4321.html                           | low |
```

output as Array is OK:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "1234"
    ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku1234.html"
    ["tag"] => string(3) "low"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "2"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "1234"
    ["url"] => string(40) "http://anotherdomain.com/alice-book.html"
    ["tag"] => string(3) "med"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "3"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "1234"
    ["url"] => string(57) "http://bookstore.com/Alices-Adventures-in-Wonderland.html"
    ["tag"] => string(3) "hig"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "4321"
    ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku4321.html"
    ["tag"] => string(3) "low"
  }
```

but if I would like to get same data **as ActiveRecord** object, the `tag` is lost.

```
$product_url = ProductUrl::find()
    ->alias('pu')
    ->select('pu.*, tag')
    ->leftJoin('shop', "SUBSTRING_INDEX(pu.url, '/', 3) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(shop.url, '/', 3)")
                //  ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

result

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(app\models\ProductUrl)#139 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(1)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku1234.html"
        }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(1)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku1234.html"
        }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(app\models\ProductUrl)#149 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(2)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(40) "http://anotherdomain.com/alice-book.html"
        }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(2)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(40) "http://anotherdomain.com/alice-book.html"
        }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  object(app\models\ProductUrl)#150 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(3)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(57) "http://bookstore.com/Alices-Adventures-in-Wonderland.html"
        }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(3)
          ["product_id"] => int(1234)
          ["url"] => string(57) "http://bookstore.com/Alices-Adventures-in-Wonderland.html"
        }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  object(app\models\ProductUrl)#151 (10) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(4)
          ["product_id"] => int(4321)
          ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku4321.html"
        }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["id"] => int(4)
          ["product_id"] => int(4321)
          ["url"] => string(31) "http://example.org/sku4321.html"
        }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

Why `tag` lost? And how to get a `tag` from joined `shop` as ActiveRecord object?

UPDATE:

**./models/Shop.php**

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "shop".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $url
 * @property string $tag
 */
 ...
```

**./models/ProductUrl.php**

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "product_url".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $product_id
 * @property string $url
 *
 * @property Product $product
 * @property Shop $shop
 */

...

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getShop()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Shop::className(), ["SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3)" => "SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3)"]);
}
```

**./controllers/ProductController.php**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\ProductUrl;
use app\models\Shop;
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subquery in SELECT using Yii2 ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50581521/subquery-in-select-using-yii2-activerecord)

Comment: @rob006 no, since I have $tag property in a model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't, since var_dump does not show `tag` property in `ProductUrl`, and no snippet of code you pasted in question proves existence of this property.

Comment: @rob006 I have property string $tag in Shop.php. Should I have property string $tag in ProductUrl.php also? I'm in doubt.

Comment: An Active Record has all the columns of the specific model in use only. If you want to get joined columns you need to see how relational  data works: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data

Comment: Your `->all()` call returns array of `ProductUrl` instances. If `ProductUrl` does not have `tag` property, then Yii is not able to store `tag` column for query and simply drops it. That is why you need `ProductUrl::$tag` defined explicitly.

Comment: Alternatively you could use relations, but `["SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3)" => "SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3)"]` in `$this->hasOne()` is incorrect - these needs to be columns, since Yii will use them to map objects. It is not possible if you use expressions in that way.

Comment: @EmrahEngin thanks for your attention. I do the same as in manual. I have     `/**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
            return $this->hasOne(Shop::className(), ['id' => 'product_id']);
    }
` in **./models/ProductUrl.php** like in manual, but when I call ` $product_url = ProductUrl::find()
                     ->getShop()
                     ->all();
` there is an error `Calling unknown method: yii\db\ActiveQuery::getShop()`. Why unknown if it exists?

Comment: @rob006 thanks, bro! Added `public $tag` in ProductUrl class. Now it fills with `tag` value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @rob006.
It is necessary explicitly define `ProductUrl::$tag` with `public $tag;` in ProductUrl class like in manual [selecting-extra-fields](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#selecting-extra-fields). Relation with `public function getShop()` is not required.