# Yii Missing attribute when using join() + one()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I don't know if this is correct behavior of Yii Active Record, consider I have this code

```php
$post = Post::find()
    ->alias('p')
    ->select(['p.*', 'COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count'])
    ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'comments c', 'p.id = c.post_id')
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->one();
```

I cannot access `$post->comment_count`, but when I use `->asArray()->one`, I can access `$post['comment_count']`, is it possible to return as Post model while having access to `comment_count`? As this can be used for validation, example

```php
// $post from code above
if ($post->comment_count != 0) {
    throw new UnprocessableEntityHttpException('Cannot delete post with comment(s)');
}

return $post->delete();
```

Comment: You need to add `comment_count` property in `Post` class in order to assign this value from query to model. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50587356/5812455

Comment: Side note: are you sure you want to group by `c.id` and not `p.id`?

Comment: @MichalHynčica ah yes, what I meant is `p.id` thanks for correction

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$comment_count` inside the `Post` model, for example:

```
class Post {
    public $comment_count;

    .....
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'comment_count' => 'Total Comment',
            .....
        ]
    }
```

But if you are satisfied with `asArray()` as what you mentioned earlier, I think that is enough because it's pretty faster.